# Ultra slow LTO4 read/write (2-3MB/s) SCSI + LSI Ultra 320

Tags: scsi, lto

So I've installed pcie SCSI card LSI Ultra 320 (which worked fine some time ago on Dell R710/ Dell 2950 with LTO3), during booting I have discovered that sync speed for LTO3 (ultrium 960) is only 40MB, also all speeds were ultra slow (100-106MB/min ~ 2-3MB/s).

I thought that maybe it is enclosure so I have installed LTO4 (Ultrium 1760) but same issue (sync speed 40, when installed inside then sync speed 160), ultra slow speeds (same issue on Dell T610 and even on personal PC).

I can't check the card in old Dell's as those units are in storage and I have to wait till Tuesday to get them back...

Does any one have any idea what is going on ? Before I was getting full LTO3 speeds (3400-4000 MB/min for LTO3)

Would it be dead SCSI card ???

Comment: In my experience the leading cause for slow operation on LTO4 drives has always been wear on the tape heads. Other reasons for slow operation have included firmware bugs and dirty fiberchannel connectors.

Comment: Same issue occur on 2 different tape drives, exactly same speeds.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/1006123 probably the same issue here (SCSI card needs restored to defaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my PCIe LSI SCSI controller has some issues, I've connected enclosure to another server with PCIX SCSI controller and job rate on LTO4 going over 9600MB/min and LTO3 ~4400MB/min.